# Copying dynamically one array of structures to another array of structures in C

Tags: c, struct

I have to copy the elements of one array of structure to blank elements of a new array of structures (all dynamically allocated). Every element of the array of structures I have, structure 'a', has only two columns, `left_column` and `right_column`.  Some of the right column entries of each element of structure `a` (say, i'th structure element) matches the left column entry of the next (viz., i+1 th) structure element of the same structure `a`.  I am attempting to find such matching entries and I am attempting to copy the entire left and right column of the matching elements one-by-one to a smaller, conserved structure, structure `b`.  The problem is **the code is compiling, but it is not getting into the all-important matching part, viz., the `if` part**.  It is getting into the `while` loop.

Kept below are the information and sample data.  This code has come to this stage due to 'PlerumCodeExperientia', I thank him.  Please suggest how to copy these matching elements.

Thanking you, Dan.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    struct a
    {
        int left_line;
        int right_line;
    };

    struct b
    {
        int conserved_left;
        int conserved_right;
    };

    FILE *fp100;    // Output File

    fp100 = fopen("Conserved_Elements.txt", "a");

    struct a *ptr1;
    int structACapacity = 3; // Only 3 such comparison files are being worked with, there are >1000 comparison files
    ptr1 = malloc(structACapacity*sizeof(struct a));

    struct b *ptr2;
    int structBCapacity = 1000;
    ptr2 = malloc(structBCapacity*sizeof(struct b));

    int structure_ctr;
    int number_of_line_comparison_files = 3;    // Only 3 for the time being
    int knt;
    int left, right;

    for (structure_ctr=0; structure_ctr < number_of_line_comparison_files; structure_ctr++) {

        knt = 0;

        while (((ptr1+knt) < (ptr1+structACapacity-1)) && (knt < 500)) {
            fprintf(fp100, "Getting Into While\n");

            // finding the matching entries between right column of knt and left column of (knt+1)
            if ((ptr1+knt)->right_line == (ptr1+(1+knt))->left_line) {
                fprintf(fp100,"\tGetting Into the If\n");

                // copying matching values to the struct b
                left = (ptr2+knt)->conserved_left = (ptr1+knt)->left_line;
                right = (ptr2+knt)->conserved_right = (ptr1+knt)->right_line;

                //fprintf(fp100,"C-Left:%d\tC-Right:%d\tLeft%d\tRight%d\n",(ptr2+knt)->conserved_left,(ptr2+knt)->conserved_right,left,right);
                // left, right are there for convinience only - easier to see, same values
                fprintf(fp100,"C-Left:%d\tC-Right:%d\n", left,right);
            }

            ++knt;    
        } // end of while
    } //end of for
}
```

The files look: 
A fragment of the first structure element looks like:

```
17   216

26   119

28    16

29   122

59   124

60   116

62   114

63   112

66    61

69    54

70    51

71    62

91    40

99    38
```

A fragment of the Second element looks like:

```
321    25

110    45

116    49

216    110

56     117

54     131

32     167

31     178

8      188

12     199

39     239

60     244

121    263

124    275
```

A fragment of the 3rd element looks like:

```
75    223

61    248

45    278

31    290

10    291

111   311

117   324

128   338

139   347

148   365

167   376

178   381

191   394

193   397
```

etc..., there are many such elements.  All of them contain such unformatted two columns of integers.

In case if you are interested to see how the content of the original file was loaded into 'structure_a', the next piece is given. It works fine.

for(q=0; q < number_of_line_comparison_files; q++)  // going through the total number of files

```
{

// File Name Etc ..

    while (fgets(file_line,99,line_comparison_file)!= NULL)

    {

    ++number_of_lines ; // Integer


    for(j=0;j<6;j++)    

            string_left_line[j]=file_line[j];


    for(j=0;j<6;j++)

            string_right_line[j]=file_line[6+j];


           left_line = atoi(string_left_line);

           right_line = atoi(string_right_line);

          *(&(ptr1+q)->left_line) = left_line;

          *(&(ptr1+q)->right_line) = right_line;

    fprintf(fp100,"Left:%d\tRight:%d\n",(ptr1+q)->left_line,(ptr1+q)->right_line);


    }   // END OF THE 'WHILE'


fprintf(fp100,"\n\n\t==================================  ================================\n\n");
```

}   // End of For

- Dan

Comment: Do you really expect someone to be able to read this mess?  Format your code properly, please.

Comment: Why use two different structs with the exact same definition? Consider disposing `b` and just using `a` for both arrays. Additionally, what do you mean when you say it doesn't work? What do you expect as the output? What's `fp100`?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the post now, it looks a bit better now .. Also, I have a bad-habit of keeping long names for variables .. sorry again.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding your goal, but why are you getting the address of anything?  Don't you just want to get the values of your arrays and compare them?  Don't use "&" to get the address of.  Just simply deference the pointers with "*".

Comment: Dear juan.facorro, fp100 is going to the temporary output file and the identical looking second structure is to keep the common elements..

Comment: And the reason he states not to make 2 structs is because you can just create two variables of different names under that struct type.  You could even make it simpler by using a typedef.  EDIT:  Also, it would help if you showed us what values you store in each structure array.  How could we do any testing without it.

Comment: are you sure your code compiles? This code fragment in your `while` condition should throw compile error: `&(ptr1+structure_ctr)`. `ptr1+structure_ctr` is an rvalue and applying `&` operator to an rvalue is wrong.

Comment: The information and code snippet you have provided is incomplete. You should check you `for` and `while` loop, and `if` conditions. Also please explain what are you trying to do in the loop.

Comment: Dear Ajay, thank you for you thoughts.. Well, I don't know why, but it compiled nicely without errors and warnings.. I didn't know precisely how much of information is necessary, I am sorry; please let me know what all you need, I'll be more than happy to tell you.. Suffice to say is that ***the other parts of this huge code is running fine***, but only for this portion, either the control skipping it altogether or the control is getting into an infinite loop or it assigns 0 to output elements.. I'll deeply appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

I must say that, there should be a little more information, for the question to be completely clear.
With the given data, this is my answer. At least the part of what I assume is asked.
I hope it helps.

```
// copy_pointer_struct.c

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    struct a
    {
        int left_line;
        int right_line;
    };

    struct b
    {
        int conserved_left;
        int conserved_right;
    };

    FILE *fp100;
    fp100 = fopen("struct_file.txt", "a");

    struct a* ptr1;
    int structACapacity = 3;
    ptr1=(struct a*)malloc(structACapacity*sizeof(struct a));

    struct b *ptr2;
    int structBCapacity = 1000;
    ptr2=(struct b*)malloc(structBCapacity*sizeof(struct b));

    // for writing test values to ptr1 array
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < structACapacity; i++ )
    {
        ptr1[i].left_line = i;
        (ptr1+i)->right_line = i+1;
    }

    int structure_ctr,
        number_of_line_comparison_files = 10,
        knt;

    // This outer for is neccessary only if you are getting structs form another source - a file for example or another structure.
    //for(structure_ctr=0; structure_ctr < number_of_line_comparison_files; structure_ctr++)
    {
        // this inner for would be neccessary if you had an 2 dimensional array of structs or a pointer to a pointer to struct.
        //for(knt=0; knt<500; knt++)
        {
            knt = 0;
            // in your while condition there is no changing value, (change being made inside cycle or condition itself),
            // which results in an infinite (for condition true) cycle or 0 cycles (for condition false)

            // this particular condition works until we have reached 500th element or the end of array,
            // whichever has lower value.
            // Of course in case of use of outer for ( && knt < 500) wouldn't be used, depending of the goal you have.
            while( (ptr1+knt) < (ptr1+structACapacity-1) && knt < 500 )
            {
                if( (ptr1+knt)->right_line == (ptr1+1+knt)->left_line ) // comment line for file test
                {
                    // copying duplicate values to the struct b
                    int left = (ptr2+knt)->conserved_left = (ptr1+1+knt)->left_line;
                    int right = (ptr2+knt)->conserved_right = (ptr1+knt)->right_line;

                    // here you can write those values to a file as 2 integers, for example
                    fprintf(fp100,"%d %d\n", left, right);
                }
                ++knt;
            } // while
        }//
    } //for structure_ctr
    fclose(fp100);
}
```

Perhaps this addition helps:

```
// copy_pointer_struct.c

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct a
{
    int left_line;
    int right_line;
} structA;

typedef struct b
{
    int conserved_left;
    int conserved_right;
} structB;

int fillColumnPtr(FILE* source, structA* ptr);



int main(int argc, char* args[])
{


    FILE *fp100;
    fp100 = fopen("struct_file.txt", "w");

    structA* ptr1;
    int structACapacity = 1000;
    ptr1=(structA*)malloc(structACapacity*sizeof(struct a));

    printf("kapacitet ptr1: %d\n", sizeof ptr1);

    structB *ptr2;
    int structBCapacity = 1000;
    ptr2=(struct b*)malloc(structBCapacity*sizeof(struct b));


    char *filename = "columns_file4.txt";
    FILE *cfile1 = fopen(filename, "r");

    printf("Loading values from file: %s . . . \n", filename);

    int number_of_lines = fillColumnPtr(cfile1, ptr1);

    fclose(cfile1);
    printf("Done.\n\n");
    printf("Values loaded to ptr1(total lines %d):\n", number_of_lines);

    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < number_of_lines; i++  )
    {
        printf("left: %6d, right: %6d\n", ptr1[i].left_line, ptr1[i].right_line);
    }

    printf("\nProcessing...\n");
    int structure_ctr,
        number_of_line_comparison_files = 10,
        knt;

    knt = 0;

    while( (ptr1+knt) < (ptr1+structACapacity-1) && knt < number_of_lines )
    {
        if( (ptr1+knt)->right_line == (ptr1+1+knt)->left_line ) // comment line for file test
        {
            // copying duplicate values to the struct b
            int left = (ptr2+knt)->conserved_left = (ptr1+1+knt)->left_line;
            int right = (ptr2+knt)->conserved_right = (ptr1+knt)->right_line;

            // here you can write those values to a file as 2 integers, for example
            fprintf(fp100,"%d %d\n", left, right);
            printf("%d %d\n", left, right);
        }
        ++knt;
    } // while
    fclose(fp100);
}

// function: transfers data from a source file to pointer to struct
int fillColumnPtr(FILE* source, structA* ptr)
{
    char file_line[20],
         *str_left_line = calloc(sizeof(char), 6),
         str_right_line[6];
    int left_line, right_line, j, line_counter = 0, i = 0;
    while ( fgets(file_line, 19, source) != NULL )
    {
        printf(">>  fileline: %s", file_line);
        for(j=0;j<6;j++)
        {
            str_left_line[j]=file_line[j];
            str_right_line[j]=file_line[6+j];
        }
        left_line = atoi(str_left_line);
        right_line = atoi(str_right_line);
        printf("  left right: %-3d %6d\n", left_line, right_line);
        ptr[i].left_line = left_line;
        ptr[i].right_line = right_line;
        ++i;
        ++line_counter;
    }
    return line_counter;
}
```

Note: I examined few of your source values, that are supposed to be in a file - non of them satisfies the condition inside `if`, resulting in an empty pointer.
The additional posted, I have tested with altered values and it works. 
For this method check the spacing in rows.
Contents of the "columns_file4.txt":

```
321    25
25     45
116    49
216    110
110    117
54     131
32     167
31     178
178    188
12     199
199    239
60     244
121    263
124    275
```

// End of file
In this file there are equal values for example:
(row 1 col right)25  == (row 2 col left )25, 110 , 178, 199.
If this is not what you are looking for, then alter the `if` condition.
Good luck.
Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you 'PlerumCodeExperientia'.. I am leaving for an hour or so, after coming back I will definitely try this and let you know if I have questions. Thanking you again. - Dan

Comment: your `main` signature is not standards compliant.

Comment: A valid argument.Method main in C should have (void) or (int argc, *argv[]) parameters. I've made corrections accordigly.

Comment: Dear 'PlerumCodeExperientia', thank you for your suggestion and for understanding the problem; however, upon implementing it, the 'left' and '(ptr2+knt)->conserved_left' and also the 'right' and '(ptr2+knt)->conserved_right' are showing only 0. I printed them normally, viz., with %d.. ... -  Can you please suggest what can be done to fix this?

Thanking you, 
- Dan.

Comment: If you were using the latest code (one with the file support), make an attempt with the if line commented. Reason: if there are no values to match the condition, nothing will be copied to ptr2.

Comment: Or, you can uncomment the test int i; for(i =0;.. block and also the fclose.

Comment: With this last edition, values (1 1 and 2 2), are written to "struct_file.txt" file, every time you start the program. file is in the same directory as your sorce file. Hope this helps.

Comment: For output to console, after 'fprint', add the following line 'printf("%d %d\n", left, right);'

Comment: Dear PlerumCodeExperientia, sorry for my delaying, I was trying out things .. I tested with your old version and it was printing all the last values of a file.. For example, the last values of File1-2 and File2-3 ; furthermore these last values do not always have matching entries on the next file .. I was printing the 'left' and '(ptr2+knt)->conserved_left' and also the 'right' and '(ptr2+knt)->conserved_right'.. It was printing the chunk of last values of whatever I input as structACapacity .. I will try your latest suggestion too and let you know what happens. Thanks of course. -Dan

Comment: Dear PlerumCodeExperientia, your latest version is not working. It is getting into the While loop, but the most-important If part, which matches the right column of ith structure with the left column of (i+1)th structure - is getting skipped .. Program is not getting in there.. . I am trying to copy to the 'conserved' structure(viz. ptr 4) the left column and the right column of each such entry(each line accessed by 'knt' variable of ptr 3) where the right column of ith structure matches with the left column of (i+1)th structure.. .. Not happening.. Please suggest. Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Can you post your source code?
I have tested current version and it is writing to file, following:
1 1
2 2

Comment: I have posted the source code part with details. If I miss some more details, please let me know. Thanking you, - Dan.

Comment: From the modified code: array ptr1 contains no values. It seems to me that you want to first load values form the file into the ptr and then process them. Is that the case?

Comment: Exactly, then we can straightaway copy both the left and right column for every i(right)-to-i+1(left) matched structure element from structure_a into a corresponding element of structure_b.. If the 'if' part runs then it probably won't matter whether we put these matching elements in an array or in structure.. Furthermore, since it is needed to contain the entire info., the 1-D array won't do. Hence, I thought of straightaway saving them in another , viz., 'conserved' structure, that is, the 'structure b'.. Thanks, -Dan.

Comment: Do you have the code that is loading data from file to ptr1?

Comment: Yes, it is loading nicely from the file. It is reading the file-content as a string and then assigning the integer entries with 'atoi' for every structure element.. That part is working fine. If you want I can put that part here also, maybe in the original post-area I will put that. Please let me know. Thanks, -Dan.